# PHAsset: What is 'assetSource'?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, photokit, phasset

I am enumerating a PHFetchResult. If I do a println on the PHAssets being returned, I get this:

```
<PHAsset: 0x178192140> 4CBE5A4F-90BD-438B-954E-6FF1B14538CD/L0/001 mediaType=1/0, assetSource=3, (2448x3264), creationDate=2014-10-15 14:20:12 +0000, location=1, hidden=0, favorite=1
```

Does anyone know what the `assetSource=3` bit is? I would like to run a predicate on the assetSource if possible but can't find any information anywhere on what it is or how to access it. Is it private?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`assetSource` is a private variable, so its meaning is purposefully opaque.

You *could* use a predicate to filter on `assetSource` from its `description` to investigate further, like [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25984109/how-do-i-determine-if-a-phasset-in-a-phfetchresult-represents-a-deleted-photo), but it'd be a purely academic exercise.

Comment: Thanks for that. Interesting to know it could be done that way but I better find another way to achieve what I was originally after.

Answer (score 0):

maybe related to upcoming PHAssetSourceType in iOS9.

```
struct PHAssetSourceType : OptionSetType {
init(rawValue rawValue: UInt)
static var TypeNone: PHAssetSourceType { get }
static var TypeUserLibrary: PHAssetSourceType { get }
static var TypeCloudShared: PHAssetSourceType { get }
static var TypeiTunesSynced: PHAssetSourceType { get }
```

}

refer to https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHAsset_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/struct/c:@E@PHAssetSourceType

Comment: Impossible! "assetSource" can be 3, but PHAssetSourceType can only be 0, 1, 2, 4.

Comment: @mayqiyue obviously asserSource is made by OR-ing of different PHAssetSourceType