# PhotoKit frameWork : What is assetSource of PHAsset?

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary, photokit, phasset

When I print the description of  **PHAsset** , it includes **assetSource=3** or **assetSource=0.** May I know what does this *assetSource* mean? What are the numbers like 3,0 related to? As per my observation for a particular PHAsset  with assetSource=3 its *ALAssetsLibrary defaultRepresentation URL* includes **ext=MOV** and PHAsset with assetSource = 0 its *ALAssetsLibrary defaultRepresentation URL* includes **ext=mov**. Does the assets-library URL ext and assetSource are related? I request somebody to clarify my questions.

*I have gone through following link [PHAsset: What is 'assetSource'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26393286/phasset-what-is-assetsource). But dint not get clarification.*

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHAsset: What is 'assetSource'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26393286/phasset-what-is-assetsource)

Answer (score 1):

maybe related to upcoming PHAssetSourceType in iOS9.

```
        struct PHAssetSourceType : OptionSetType { init(rawValue rawValue: UInt)
static var TypeNone: PHAssetSourceType { get }
static var TypeUserLibrary: PHAssetSourceType { get }
static var TypeCloudShared: PHAssetSourceType { get }
static var TypeiTunesSynced: PHAssetSourceType { get }
}
```

refer to https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHAsset_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/struct/c:@E@PHAssetSourceType

Answer (score 0):

Okay, well, let me rephrase the link you checked out.

There are public and private properties. These exist in Apple's frameworks too. Apple wants you to touch the public properties (declared in .h), but they don't want you to see the private properties (declared in .m).

So, `assetSource` is a private property that apple uses internally, meaning you shouldn't touch it as its an internal framework thing. You only see it when printing the description because its still a property. You just can't access it, neither will you know what the numbers mean.

I'm assuming the numbers are some internal enum for the source of the file, but once again, internal = you shouldn't mind it, its Apple's private properties.