# Can you get the photos in "Recently Deleted" using PhotoKit?

Tags: ios, ios8, photokit, photosframework

I've scanned the API and found nothing so far. I'd take a `PHAssetCollection` for "Recently Deleted", or a way to fetch the individual `PHAsset`s.

I'm not recommending (or disrecommending), but there are some solutions *outside* the API, and yet possibly still AppStore-passable:

1. You can use an undocumented smart album id for "Recently Deleted", `1000000201`. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269867).
2. You can filter on the text `"assetSource=3"` in `PHAsset.description`, See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26176755/45813).

Comment: Similar question about collections: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269867/how-to-know-if-an-phassetcollection-is-the-recently-deleted-collection