# How to know if an PHAssetCollection is the recently deleted collection?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, photokit

There is a subtype for the recently added collection: `PHAssetCollectionSubtypeSmartAlbumRecentlyAdded`. However there is no
`assetCollectionSubtype` that would identify the "Recently Deleted" collection.

This is the description of the "Recently Deleted" collection in my case:

`(iOS 8.1.3): DF876BFD-...-C97F4628467C/L0/040 Recently Deleted assetCollectionType=2/1000000201`

This indicates it is of type `PHAssetCollectionTypeSmartAlbum`. But what the heck is subtype `1000000201`?

`201` should be `PHAssetCollectionSubtypeSmartAlbumPanoramas` according to the docs.

Can the magic number `1000000201` be trusted to never change? Probably not.

However, this is how you can retrieve the recently deleted collection:

```
PHFetchResult *smartAlbums = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeSmartAlbum subtype:1000000201 options:nil];
```

There is a major difference in this particular smart album: the `PHAsset`s can not be deleted (again), because this is the trash. So it'd be essential to know if a delete option should be presented to the user.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: did you find any other way apart from the localizedTitle to identify the deleted Albums

Comment: Hi, does anyone know of a more up-to-date method for doing this?

Comment: As of end of 2021, this magic number `1000000201` still seems to be valid: `<PHAssetCollection: 0x7f82dea22c50> 72053882-BF20-4D4A-B1A5-03D1DDAE1707/L0/040, title:"Recently Deleted", subtitle:"(null)" assetCollectionType=2/1000000201`

Answer (score -1):

Regarding picking out the "Recently Deleted" collection, here's a workaround.

```
PHFetchResult *smartAlbums = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeSmartAlbum
                                                                      subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeAlbumRegular
                                                                      options:nil];

__block PHAssetCollection *recentlyDeletedCollection;
[smartAlbums enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(PHAssetCollection *smartAlbum, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([smartAlbum.localizedTitle isEqualToString:@"Recently Deleted"]) {
        NSLog(@"Recently Deleted album is at %ld", idx);
        recentlyDeletedCollection = smartAlbums[idx];
    }
}];
```

Comment: This would only work for English given that it's a "localizedTitle" I think.