# How to delete PHAsset permanently from device("Photos") in iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, phasset

How to delete the `PHAsset` from device permanently to get more space on device immediately?

I could only find the following API to delete `PHAsset` from the Photos app which is moving the assets to "Recently Deleted" album which is still holding memory on the device,

```
PHAssetChangeRequest.deleteAssets((assets as NSArray))
```

Is there a solution to delete assets (programmatically) from the Photos app permanently?

Comment: Have you tried smth like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26934562/can-you-get-the-photos-in-recently-deleted-using-photokit ?

Comment: I doubt it. Apps could abuse it if this was allowed.

Comment: @aheze You know iOS is already confirming with the user by showing the delete popup with assets even if we do `PHAssetChangeRequest.deleteAssets`. So the same way they can allow to remove the assets permanently.

Answer (score 0):

No Apple doesn't allow any external apps to remove any photo from "Recently Deleted". The only delete API is `deleteAssets`